# Listing continuous List from opencsv

Tags: java, list, collections, csv, opencsv

OK.first i realized that readAll() saved the tokenized String in array index from 0 until it sees the newline char(next row of a csv file) and start again from 0.I want the tokenized String saved in a continuous array.

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadTest {


    private static String data0 = "U:\\test-csv1.csv";
    private static String [] longArray = new String[50];
    private static String[] aString;
    private static List<String> longStr = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    private static int arrayCtr = 0;

    private static  void copyArray(String aTemp){

        longStr.add(arrayCtr, aTemp);
        System.out.println(arrayCtr);
        arrayCtr++;
        }

    private static void printElements(){

        for(int no =15;no<= 25;no++)
        System.out.print("\nelNo "+no+" is: "+longStr.get(no));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(data0),';');
    List aList;



        while ((aList = reader1.readAll())!= null){
            int outer= 0;
            String aTemp;
            String [] longArray = new String[50];
```

so here i make a loop to copy the tokenized String to be copied into a List called longStr.

```
            for (int counter= 0;counter <aList.size();counter++){
                String [] tempStr = (String[]) aList.get(counter);
                for (int j = 0; j < tempStr.length; j++){

                    aTemp = tempStr[j];
                    copyArray(aTemp);
                //  System.out.print(tempStr[j]);
                //  System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("strNo: " + j+"="+tempStr[j] + " "+"\n");
                    System.out.print("TEMP="+aTemp+"\n");


                }
```

this is a counter to obtain the num of row.

```
                System.out.println("loop for no. of element:"+(++outer));
                System.out.println();


                        printElements();
            }
```

printElements is a method to list down the elements in longStr.

I am having a problem in listing all the elements in longStr.  This is what I have so far, I tried to arrange tokenized String from readAll() into continuous array as in longStr.  When I tried to print out the elements after readAll() finished reading the csv file, it continuously print the elements from printElements() ie nonstop. How do I solve this, and where can I put the printElements() other than inside the `while`? I always get error like indexoutofbound if I place it somewhere else.

Comment: I've tidied up your post a bit, but fundamentally I still don't understand what it is you're asking.  Could you try re-reading your post from the context of someone who's not familiar, and think about phrasing it more clearly?  (Starting with your problem rather than a big block of code would help too.)

Comment: what is your code trying to do? just guessing, you could probably achieve the same thing in way less code. change your loops to foreach style ie: for (String x : aList) { //do something }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
while ((aList = reader1.readAll())!= null){
```

is an endless loop. try

```
if((aList = reader1.readAll())!= null){
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call `reader.readAll()` and then iterate over that List?

```
List<String[]> records = reader.readAll();
for (String[] record : records) {
  //do something with each record
}
```